# SOAP request not returning a response

Tags: php, curl, soap

I am making a request to a search directory that looks up HIV specialists. Here is the documentation they provide: http://mobile.aahivm.org/getinfo.asmx?op=GetProviders

I use PHP's cUrl to make the request. Any idea why nothing is being returned?

```
<?php

$curlData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetProviders xmlns="http://localhost">
      <fname></fname>
      <lname></lname>
      <locationzip></locationzip>
      <locationcity></locationcity>
      <locationstate>New York</locationstate>
      <locationcountry></locationcountry>
      <primaryservicesid></primaryservicesid>
      <credentials></credentials>
      <specialty></specialty>
      <specialtycare></specialtycare>
      <support></support>
      <paymentoptions></paymentoptions>
      <member></member>
    </GetProviders>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>'; 

$url='http://mobile.aahivm.org/getinfo.asmx?op=GetProviders';


$curl = curl_init();
$length = strlen($curlData);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array (

    'POST /getinfo.asmx HTTP/1.1',
    'Host: mobile.aahivm.org',
    'Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8',
     'Content-Length:'=>$length,
    'SOAPAction: "http://localhost/GetProviders"' 

));

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlData);

//$result = substr(curl_exec($curl), 285, -72); ///remove SOAP envelope!


$result = curl_exec($curl); 
print_r("Curl result: ".$result."<br><br><hr>");


curl_close ($curl);


$arr2 = array();
$arr2[] = json_decode($result, true);


////

 foreach ($arr2 as $key=>$value) {
    //echo $value;
    $next[] = $value;
        foreach ($next as $key=>$value) {
        //echo $value;
        $next[] = $value;
            foreach ($next as $key=>$value) {
            echo $key."=".$value."<br />";
            }
            echo "--<br /><br />";
        }   

 }

 /////
 ?>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, $result is null, or does it come back as an empty array?

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking to retrieve all of the providers in the response?
In their documentation (http://mobile.aahivm.org/getinfo.asmx?op=GetProviders) it says " The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values." So im assuming you will need to send with your request, some sort of values for it to search for.

Hope this helps a bit